# Change default dash（“-”）to blank in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-table

I have a web app, frontend has a bootstrap table, backend using Restful API to render the data.

In the bootstrap table, the null value displays dash by default.

I want to change the default dash to blank for all the data.

I have tried this method:[Bootstrap table, dashes / hyphens in empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483029/bootstrap-table-dashes-hyphens-in-empty-cells),

```
    $('#bk-table').bootstrapTable({
        undefinedText: ''
    });
```

But it did not worked for me, the table still displays dash as default for null value, and in the console no error shows.

How could I change default dash（“-”）to blank  in bootstrap table?

Comment: That's should be ok, so could you provide jsFiddle or another online editor link for this issue?

Comment: What does your `null` value look like? is the object showing from API as `null` or `undefined` for no value? Also make sure you are using the current version of this library. Your code should work as shown above.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping My null value is a null in the MySQL database

Comment: can you share a JSfiddle or reproducible example of your issue to help you further?